# List does not expand after adding a new value in flutter using value from Barcode Scanner

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm working on a project in Flutter and I'm new to this. Every time I scan a code, it should add the new value to the list. I've tried doing that but instead of adding the new value, it replaces the existing value. Here is my code --

```
 List data = jsonDecode(snapshot.data.toString()) as List;
 var values = new List<String>();

  int x = data.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    var z = data[i]['id'];
    print(barcode);

    if (barcode == z) {
      if (!values.contains(barcode)) {
        values.add(z);
      }

      return new ListView.builder(
        itemCount: values == null ? 0 : values.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return new Card(
            child: new Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                ListTile(
                  title: new Text("" + values[index]),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      );
    } else {
      print("failed");
    }
  }

return new Text('Hello');
}
```

Below is the output, I get:

```
I/flutter ( 7840): 066613702021
I/flutter ( 7840): failed
I/flutter ( 7840): 066613702021
```

Comment: Why do you return the ListView.builder inside for loop?

Comment: @Abhishek I was trying to have it return a card after each scan matches a id, been stuck on this for 4 days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you might know flutter is based on stateless widgets that has its lifecycle within frames. The way you interact with widget is basically by saying to flutter that something changed in your app and it should reschedule to draw changes to the user.

In this case, every time you scan a new barcode, invoke [setState method](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html)

So that the framework gets notifyied that something changed.

The documentation states it

**setState method**

> Notify the framework that the internal state of this object has changed.
>     Whenever you change the internal state of a State object, make the 
>     change in a function that you pass to setState:

Comment: Setting the state did the job, this was very helpful. Thanks very much.

Comment: @Raheem Campbell happy to help. Please, flag this answer as correct.